# NPE in AjaxHandler.applyAttachedObject when adding f:ajax to compositecomponent

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, composite-component

I have created a composite component around primefaces 5.1 datatable:

The component without AJAX (`selectorServicio2.xhtml`)

```
<ui:component
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

  <cc:interface componentType="selectorServicio2">
    <cc:attribute name="servicios" required="true" type="java.util.Collection"
      shortDescription="Colección de servicios entre los que se buscarán los datos"/>
    <cc:attribute name="seleccionSimpleAttr" type="es.imasmallorca.selene.model.prestacion.Servicio"/>
    <cc:attribute name="seleccionMultipleAttr" type="java.util.List"/>
    <cc:attribute name="seleccionMultiple" required="false" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="false"/>
    <cc:attribute name="scrollHeight" required="false" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
  </cc:interface>

  <cc:implementation>
    <p:dataTable id="selectorServicio" widgetVar="#{cc.widgetId}"
      value="#{cc.attrs.servicios}" var="_servicio"
      scrollable="#{not empty cc.attrs.scrollHeight}"   scrollHeight="#{cc.attrs.scrollHeight}"
      selectionMode="#{cc.attrs.seleccionMultiple ? 'multiple' : 'single'}"
      selection="#{cc.attrs.seleccionMultiple ? cc.attrs.seleccionMultipleAttr : cc.attrs.seleccionSimpleAttr}" rowKey="#{_servicio.codigo}">

      <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{_servicio.entidad.nombre}"/>
      </p:column>

      <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{_servicio.tipoServicio.nombre}"/>
      </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
  </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

It has a backing class (`SelectorServicio2.java`):

```
@FacesComponent("selectorServicio2")
public class SelectorServicio2 extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SelectorServicio2.class.getName());

  private static final String ID_SERVICIOS_SELECCIONADOS = "ServiciosSeleccionados";

  @Override
  public String getFamily() {
    return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
  }

  public void encodeBegin(FacesContext facesContext) throws IOException {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Servicio> servicios = (List<Servicio>) this.getAttributes().get("servicios");
    if (servicios == null) {
      servicios = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    Collections.sort(servicios, new ServicioPorNombreEntidadTipoServicio(Criterio.ENTIDAD_TIPOSERVICIO));
    getStateHelper().put("servicios", servicios);
    getStateHelper().put(ID_SERVICIOS_SELECCIONADOS, new ArrayList<Servicio>());

    super.encodeBegin(facesContext);
  }

  @Override
  public Object getValue() {
    ArrayList<Servicio> servicios = new ArrayList<>();
    Servicio servicio = (Servicio) this.getStateHelper().get("servicio");
    if (servicio != null) {
      servicios.add(servicio);
    }
    return servicios;
  }

  public String getWidgetId() {
    return "wdgSelectorServicio2_" + this.getClientId().replace(":", "_");
  }

  public void setServicioSeleccionado(Servicio servicioSeleccionado) {
    if (servicioSeleccionado == null) {
      this.getStateHelper().remove("servicio");
    } else {
      this.getStateHelper().put("servicio", servicioSeleccionado);
    }
  }

  public Servicio getServicioSeleccionado() {
    return (Servicio) this.getStateHelper().get("servicio");
  }
}
```

This works as expected (`text.xhtml`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:imas="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
  <h:form>
    <imas:selectorServicio2 id="serviceSelector"
      servicios="#{testBean.services}"
      seleccionSimpleAttr="#{testBean.selectedService}"
      scrollHeight="110">
    </imas:selectorServicio2>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Now, to add Ajax support, I do:

1. Add `<cc:clientBehavior name="servicioSeleccionado" event="rowSelect" targets="selectorServicio"/>` to the `cc:interface` of `selectorServicio2.xhtml`.
2. Make `SelectorServicio2` implement `ClientBehaviorHolder` (strangely enough, I did not need to implement any method, but got no issues compiling the class).
3. Add the ajax tag to `test.xhtml`:

   ```
   <imas:selectorServicio2 id="serviceSelector"
     servicios="#{testBean.services}"
     seleccionSimpleAttr="#{testBean.selectedService}"
     scrollHeight="110">
     <f:ajax event="servicioSeleccionado" listener="#{testBean.selectService}"/>
   </imas:selectorServicio2>
   ```
4. Add the `selectService()` method to `TestBean.java`:

   ```
   public void selectService() {
     log.warning("SERVICIO SELECCIONADO !!!!");
   }
   ```

After those changes, I get a NullPointerException:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxHandler.applyAttachedObject(AjaxHandler.java:333)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxHandler.applyNested(AjaxHandler.java:258)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxHandler.apply(AjaxHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyNextHandler(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:183)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>     at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:995)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Wildfly 8.1 with standard configuracion (JSF 2.2) on Java 7

Comment: Before posting an answer, can you tell why exactly you want to implement `ClientBehaviorHolder` on the backing composite? This is namely not necessary in order to use `<f:ajax>` this way as it's just delegated to the target input which already has `ClientBehaviorHolder` implemented. Removing it from the backing component would immediately fix this problem, but perhaps you needed it for something else.

Comment: @BalusC You are right, that solved the issue, thank you. I added the `implements ClientBehaviorHolder` because I thoght, from reading the summary of the tag (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/composite/clientBehavior.html), that it was needed. If you care to write the answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: @BalusC while you are writting the answer, it might be worth noting that removing the `implements ClientBehaviorHolder` stopped the NPE, but to get the event controller called I also needed to use `p:ajax` instead of `f:ajax` (not that is a problem, just to make the answer more complete for those who read it). `f:ajax` lead to javascript problems (Mozilla 26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxHandler.applyAttachedObject(AjaxHandler.java:333)
```

Let's check the [source of AjaxHandler#applyAttachedObject()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.6/com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/jsf/core/AjaxHandler.java#333):

```
332            Collection<String> eventNames = bHolder.getEventNames();
333            if (!eventNames.contains(eventName)) {
334                throw new TagException(this.tag, 
335                    getUnsupportedEventMessage(eventName, eventNames, parent));
336            }
```

Aha, `getEventNames()` returned `null`. That method was implemented on `UIComponentBase` whose [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#getEventNames()) says the following:

> This is a default implementation of `ClientBehaviorHolder.getEventNames()`. `UIComponent` does not implement the `ClientBehaviorHolder` interface, but provides default implementations for the methods defined by `ClientBehaviorHolder` to simplify subclass implementations. Subclasses that wish to support the `ClientBehaviorHolder` contract must declare that the subclass implements `ClientBehaviorHolder`, **and must override this method to return a non-Empty `Collection` of the client event names that the component supports.**

Technically, you should be overriding `getEventNames()` in your component returning a collection of supported event names.

However, you actually didn't need it here. The `<cc:clientBehavior>` is already retargeting it on the `<p:dataTable>` component nested in the composite, which has that interface and method already properly implemented. So you should just **remove** the `ClientBehaviorHolder` interface from the backing component.

Moreover, `<f:ajax>` wouldn't work on PrimeFaces specific events, you should be using `<p:ajax>` instead. It will render a script which in turn invokes PrimeFaces-specific ajax client API.